# How to get a youtube video in my APP ? ( build with Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, youtube

I am building an APP with Phonegap and I want a youtube video in my APP. I thought I could use the cordova plugin media for this but it doesn't work. Anyone knows what's wrong with my code or how to get a youtube video in my APP? Thanks

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>       
        <title> KVL Leermomenten </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="phonegap.css">
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script> 
        <script src="javascript.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body onload="loadScript()">
        <!-- pagina 0 homepagina -->
        <section class="show" id="page0">
            <h1><img  src="img/banner.png" alt="banner" /> </h1>

            <div class="tekst" >
                <p> Welkom bij de expo ‘KVL-Leermomenten’. Afgelopen jaar zijn Oisterwijkers uitgenodigd in de huiskamer van het Leerlokaal KVL om mee te denken over de toekomst van dit gebouw. Hier is het idee ontstaan om een expositie over de geschiedenis van de Koninklijke Verenigde Lederfabriek (KVL) te organiseren. Het Leerlokaal KVL heeft dit idee vertaald in deze expo samen met ruim 240 leerlingen van 2College Durendeal uit Oisterwijk.De expo ‘KVL-Leermomenten’ maakt de geschiedenis op twee manieren zichtbaar. Zo is er enerzijds een tijdlijn van de leerfabriek te zien en anderzijds worden herinneringen aan de draaiende leerfabriek verteld, door mensen die er zelf mee te maken hebben gehad.  Deze verhalen worden nu aan jullie doorgegeven en krijgen zo weer een nieuwe toekomst.  </p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- pagina 1 rondleiding: native functie: vibrate -->
        <section class="hide" id="page1">
            <h1><img  src="img/banner_rondleiding.png" alt="banner" /> </h1>
            <div class="tekst" >
                <p> Bekijk hieronder de video waarbij je een rondleiding krijgt in de expositie.  </p>
            </div>
            <div id="playAudio" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6qFCqOy3HU" />

            <button id="volgende" />    <button id="vorige"/> 

        </section>

        <!-- pagina 2 op locatie: native functie: gps -->
        <section class="hide" id="page2">
            <h1><img  src="img/banner_oplocatie.png" alt="banner" /> </h1>
            <div class="tekst" >
                <p> Bekijk hier uw locatie.  </p>
            </div>
            <div id="GPS"> </div>
            <!-- <img id="myImage" src=""/> -->
        </section>

        <!-- pagina 3 mijn expo, native functie: camera-->
        <section class="hide" id="page3">
            <h1><img  src="img/banner_mijnexpo.png" alt="banner" /> </h1>
            <div class="tekst" >
                <p> Maak je eigen expositie over erfgoed! </p>
            </div>
            <button id="foto"> </button>
            <img id="myImage" src=""/>

        </section>

        <!-- pagina 4 rondleiding; filmpje 2 -->
        <section class="hide" id="page4">
            <h1><img  src="img/banner_rondleiding.png" alt="banner" /> </h1>
            hier komt filmpje 2

        </section>

        <!-- navigatie -->
        <nav>
            <button class="up" id="nav1"></button>
            <button class="up" id="nav2"></button>
            <button class="up" id="nav3"></button>
        </nav>

    </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
function loadScript() {
// Wait for device to be ready loading everything

onDeviceReady();
    };

// When device is ready
function onDeviceReady() {


    document.getElementById('nav1').addEventListener('mousedown', nav1Down, false); //mousedown = touchstart for app
    document.getElementById('nav1').addEventListener('mouseup',  page1Show, false); //mouseup = touchend for app
    document.getElementById('nav2').addEventListener('mousedown', nav2Down, false);
    document.getElementById('nav2').addEventListener('mouseup',  page2Show, false);
    document.getElementById('nav3').addEventListener('mousedown', nav3Down, false);
    document.getElementById('nav3').addEventListener('mouseup',  page3Show, false);
    document.getElementById('volgende').addEventListener('mousedown', volgendeDown, false);
    document.getElementById('volgende').addEventListener('mouseup',  page4Show, false);
    document.getElementById('foto').addEventListener('mousedown', fotoDown, false);
    document.getElementById('foto').addEventListener('mouseup',  fotoShow, false);
    document.getElementById('GPS').addEventListener('loadScript',  getGPS, false);
    document.getElementById('playAudio').addEventListener('loadScript',  playAudio, false);
    //document.getElementById('volgende').addEventListener('mousedown',  vibrateOn, false);
};

// Add some GUI to the touch events
function nav1Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav1').className='down';
};
function nav2Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav2').className='down';
};
function nav3Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav3').className='down';
};
function volgendeDown() {
    document.getElementById('volgende').className='down';
};

function fotoDown() {
    document.getElementById('foto').className='down';
};



// Activate the tabs
function page1Show() {
    document.getElementById('page0').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page1').className='show';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page4').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('nav1').className='up';
};
function page2Show() {
    document.getElementById('page0').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page1').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='show';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page4').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('nav2').className='up';
};

function page3Show() {
    document.getElementById('page0').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page1').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='show';
    document.getElementById('page4').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('nav3').className='up';
};

function page4Show() {
    document.getElementById('page0').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page1').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page4').className='show';
    document.getElementById('volgende').className='up';
};

//Camera
function fotoShow(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}


//GPS

// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
function getGPS() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}


var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}






//Media

function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I have not tested this, you should be able to use an IFRAME to embed the video since Cordova is simply putting your app into a webview. Youtube has an JS API for IFRAME usage that is found at https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference